# Time limit on input thread

Tags: java, input, bots

I am creating an IRC bot using Pircbot that can respond to certain requests (e.g. "!time" provides local time). One of the functions I am building is a giveaway system that randomly selects a user from the currently online users and gives them a prize.

I would like to enhance the system by forcing the winner to type "!accept" within 30 minutes of winning in order to claim the prize. However I would like the bot to still function, meaning I can't freeze the entire thread for 30 minutes waiting for a message.

A few ways I am thinking of doing it feel a bit too hacky to me.

1. I can store the winner's name in a variable or a .properties file, and constantly be on the lookout for the "!accept" command. If an "!accept" was sent by the winner (the name in the variable) and the message sent time was within 30 minutes, confirm winner. The downside to this is if the bot restarts or is taken offline temporarily in this 30 minute period, it could cause a lot of continuity problems, especially with a .properties file.
2. Create a runnable thread, sleep for 30 minutes and then check all new messages for the !accept command. This sounds extra hacky with hacky sauce on top.
3. Dance my problems away.

Comment: Mark the time you choose the winner, maybe even have another `Thread` or `Timer` event which gets triggered after 30 minutes to reset it.  If the input is "!accept" and is from the correct user AND the difference between the "marked" time and now is less then 30 minutes, happy user

Comment: Either you come back after 30 mins to check if the user wrote ```!accept```, or you have a timer thread to check this condition in a timely manner and stop after 30 mins. Both the options are valid and depends on how soon you want to detect a prospective winner has written ```!accept```

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not a bad idea... Where would you suggest I store the winner's name in the 30 minutes? .properties file or a nasty global variable?

Comment: That's up to you.  You could use a database, or a singleton manager or some other "state" object

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer, it ended up working nicely. I can set you as the answer if you provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the time you choose the winner, maybe even have another Thread or Timer event which gets triggered after 30 minutes to reset it.

If the input is `"!accept"` and is from the correct user AND the difference between the "marked" time and now is less then 30 minutes, happy user